# Combining REGEXEXTRACT and SUBSTITUTE in Google Sheets Formula

Tags: google-sheets

I'm extracting text from filename cells into separate metadata field cells. So far I have done this successfully using the REGEXTRACT formula, as seen below.

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "TILEABLE|ROOM|MAIN|FLOORSHOT|SWATCH|ANGLED")
```

However some metadata fields that include multiple words require that a space or other character be placed between words. I'm trying to figure out how to use SUBSTITUTE or REPLACE in conjunction with REGEXTRACT to find a phrase and replace it with a version with something different. Ex. Replace "TOPDOWN" with "Top Down" or replace "1TO1" with "1-to-1).

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your purpose one formula might be better than other. If you want to list in a column the substituted values of this string you could chain the number of phrases you want using [SUBSTITUTE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094215?hl=en) and [REGEXTRACT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244?hl=en).

This will return all the phrases you are looking for and substitute them to then use the formula [TRANSPOSE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094262?hl=en) to take this range and display it in a columns (as it normally would be displayed in a row and only a single value). This is a simple example:

```
=TRANSPOSE({SUBSTITUTE(REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"TOPDOWN"),"TOPDOWN","Top Down"),SUBSTITUTE(REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"SHIRTS"),"SHIRTS","Shirts1")})
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

try:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(REGEXEXTRACT(A1, 
 "TOPDOWN|1TO1|TILEABLE|ROOM|MAIN|FLOORSHOT|SWATCH|ANGLED"), 
 "TOPDOWN", "Top Down"), 
 "1TO1",    "1-to-1")
```

Comment: I get #NA: "Error
Function REGEXEXTRACT parameter 2 value "TILEABLE|ROOM|MAIN|FLOORSHOT|SWATCH|ANGLED" does not match text of Function REGEXEXTRACT parameter 1 value "MB006_00753_TOPDOWN.tif"."

Comment: Tyler, you can't SUBSTITUTE something you didn't (REGEX)EXTRACT. In player0's formula, "TOPDOWN" was not part of the REGEXEXTRACT, so it won't be extracted (and, hence, you can't SUBSTITUTE it). If you added "TOPDOWN" with the pipe separator to the REGEXEXTRACT, the formula would have returned the SUBSTITUTEd "Top Down." However, I think you're going about this the wrong way. If you share a link to your sheet (or a copy of it), those here can make the most efficient suggestions. I suspect you're currently working too hard.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.